# How to change the opacity of the border without changing its color

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm going to change opacity of input's border when it's disabled using SCSS. But border color is coming from variable:

```
$borderColor: #5985dc;

.my-input {
  border: 1px solid $borderColor;
}
.my-input:disabled {
  border-color: ???;
}
```

... or is there any way to change the color to half-transparent version?

Comment: you can use rgba format to adjust the opacity

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use Sass's `rgba()` function. It can take a hex colour value and an opacity value, and convert it to RGBA:

```
$borderColor: #5985dc;

.my-input {
  border: 1px solid $borderColor;
}
.my-input:disabled {
  border-color: rgba($borderColor, 0.5);
}
```